# row_number starting from the last number?

Tags: t-sql, row-number

by using row number, I have assigned some columns by grouping them. basically query as below.

```
update product set row_number= CONVERT(nvarchar(255),  (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by product.groupID order by product.groupID)))
```

But now there are new products and they dont have row_number (as null). I can't reassign all row_numbers. I would like to continue assigning null ones by using the last number. 
how can I do it with tsql.

basically, according to the sample table below. D should get 4, G should get 3 and H should be 1.

```
 product row_number groupID
  A         1         1
  B         2         1
  C         3         1
  D        null       1
  E         1         2
  F         2         2
  G        null       2
  H        null       3
```

Comment: partition by product.groupID order by **product.groupID** ?

Comment: Is it possible to rename this table in the background, have the updating forms point to the new table name, and replace this table name with a view that uses ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY product.groupID ORDER BY product.product) as this row_number column?

Comment: @hamlet: i think order by doesnt affect the query. But partion by is kind of grouping i believe. I saw this usage after my research on google. Anyway this workout fine for me initially. It is irrelevant to my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CTE that creates the row numbers, then update the `product` table with the results of the CTE.

```
;with cte(product, groupId, newRowNumber)
as(
select product, groupId, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by product.groupID order by product.groupID, product.product)
from product 
)

update product
set row_number = newRowNumber
from cte
where cte.groupId = product.groupId 
and cte.product = product.product
and product.row_number is null
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50a14/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**with list as
**(select ID, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by groupid order by groupid) as rn from product)
update product
set dbo.product.row_number= CONVERT(nvarchar(255), list.rn)
from list inner join dbo.product on list.ID = dbo.product.ID****